# Android Camera on Navigator

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with 'this' to use Android Camera on Navigator.

This is my code :

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Navigator,
} = React;

var Camera = require('react-native-camera'); //require the camera component
var component = '';
var capturedBase64='';
var typeCamera=Camera.constants.Type.back;

var PageCamera = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return ({
            capturedBase64: '',
            type: Camera.constants.Type.back
        });
    },

    switchCamera: function() {
        this.setState({ type: this.state.type === Camera.constants.Type.back ? Camera.constants.Type.front : Camera.constants.Type.back });
    },

    render() {
    component = this;
    return (
      <Navigator
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
          navigator={this.props.navigator}/>
    );
  },
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Camera style={styles.camera} ref="cam" type={component.state.type} captureTarget=   {Camera.constants.CaptureTarget.memory}></Camera>
                <Image
                source={{
                    isStatic: true,
                    uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + component.state.capturedBase64,
            }}
            style={styles.captured}/>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.captureButton} onPress={function() {
            component.refs.cam.capture({ sampleSize: 10 }).then(function(capturedBase64) {
                component.setState({ capturedBase64 });
                setTimeout(() => component.setState({ capturedBase64: '' }), 5000);
            });
        }}>
            <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Capture</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>

        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.switchButton} onPress={this.switchCamera}>
            <Text style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>Switch</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
    );
}
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    camera: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20
    },
    captured: {
    width: 200,
    height: 400
    },
    captureButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: 50,
    left: 50, bottom: 20, right: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 20,
    },
    switchButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: 50,
    left: 50, top: 20, right: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: 20,
    },
});

module.exports = PageCamera;
```

I have a white screen instead of my camera. I think it's a problem with my 'this' and my 'component'.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I use https://github.com/timmh/react-native-camera

Comment: When I simplify my code, I don't use this or my 'component' but my problem is here. What do you think about the renderScene and the render ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a build problem.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the function like this:

```
onPress={ () => this.switchCamera() }
```

Comment: I don't know if it's better because I don't see anything.. I have just a white screen instead of the camera.

Comment: Oh, well it may not have anything to do with the "this" reference then, and may have something to do with the implementation of the Camera? Maybe try setting a flex:1 on the camera?

Comment: It's the same thing with the flex. I see the red border of the camera but not the image. I try the example of the package and it works. I think the problem is with my navigator